# nilpotent fixed-point-free groups of automorphisms

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ be a nilpotent subgroup of
$Aut(G)$. If $C_{G}(H)=1$, is $G$ solvable?

Comment: The question is not well formulated. What do you know about the problem? Works of Shult, Gross, Khukhro and many others? What if $G$ is an Abelian group?

Comment:  I've been musing on a this question under the (very strong) extra assumption that $G$ is simple, but even this seems a little tricky. I guess that $C_G(H)$ is never trivial here, but how to prove it? One could do an exhaustive analysis of the outer automorphism group, but that seems very unsatisfactory... I may well be missing an easy solution though...

Comment: @Nick: The outer automorphism groups of all finite simple groups are well known (and very small).

Comment: Yes.The outer automorphism groups of all finite simple groups are well known and very small. But how to prove it rigorously, especially when $G$ is a simple group of Lie type?

Comment: I am sure you know this, but - using the CFSG - it is known that when $(|G|,|H|)=1$, $G$ is solvable (and you don't even need $H$ nilpotent). This shows that what you say is true when $H$ is a p-group.

Comment: Yes. When $H$ is a p-group, we can use Theorem 6.2.3 in the book "finite groups (gorenstein)" to deduce that $(|G|,|H|)=1$. So by the Classification Theorem of Finite Simple Groups, $G$ is solvable. But I don't know how to check when $G$ is a simple group of Lie type.

Comment: @MarkSapir: I don't understand the last sentence of your first comment. Why do you ask about $G$ abelian?

Comment: @MarkSapir, The problem I'm having is not understanding the outer automorphism groups of FSGs - as you say this is well understood. The problem is understanding their centralizers. Or more precisely the centralizers of their nilpotent subgroups. The centralizers of individual automorphisms are well understood - Gorenstein, Lyons, Solomon vol. 3 does the job for instance - but understanding how these things intersect (i.e. calculating subgroup centralizers) seems like a rather subtle question. I doubt a centralizer will ever be trivial but, as I said above, I think proving it might be hard.

Comment: @jp: $H$ is Abelian, not $G$.  